# Python saving file to Wrong path

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, selenium

My intention for the code bellow is to save a file inside a folder. But the file is beeing saved on the folder before the correct one.

How can i modify it so it saves the file to correct folder?

```html
    #Make Selenium check the chatroom name
    chatroom = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_19vo_').text

    #Create a variable of a folder path with chatroom name
    chat_path = 'D:\Drive\Outros\Python\data_save\chats\ ' + chatroom

    #Verify if folder already exists, if not, create it
    Path(chat_path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

    #Save a df.csv to the chatroom folder
    df.to_csv(chat_path +chatroom+' in'+ timestr +' .csv', index=None, header=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: Why `chat_path +chatroom` in the `to_csv` call ? `chat_path` already ends with `chatroom`.

Comment: I want the CSV to have the chatroom name too

Comment: Oh, so are you missing a directory separator ?
`df.to_csv(chat_path + '/' +chatroom+' in'+ timestr +' .csv', index=None, header=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')`

Comment: It worked. Thanks! If you want to send an formal answer i will be happy to accept it!

Comment: use `.joinpath` `Path(chat_path).joinpath(f'chatroom in {timestr}.csv')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a directory separator:

```
df.to_csv(chat_path + '/' +chatroom+' in'+ timestr +' .csv', index=None, header=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

The best practice is to use `os.path.join`:

```
import os
chat_filename = '%s in%s.csv' % (chatroom, timestr)
df.to_csv(os.path.join(chat_path, chat_filename), index=None, header=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using double \ in your path.

```
 chat_path = 'D:\\Drive\\Outros\\Python\\data_save\\chats\\ ' + chatroom
```

Comment: Just tried, it did not save the file in to the folder